# Where can I get themes for my Posterous Blog

Tags: posterous

They only have a few options and when you compare to other blog services it seems very lacking.  I'm hoping there's some sort of repository out there I haven't bumped into yet.

Answer (score 2):

Posterous blogged about this here: http://blog.posterous.com/posterous-theming-its-here-its-live-and-its-t

In this example they show how to port themes from other blogs http://posterous.com/theming/porting

Answer (score 1):

Apart from http://themes.posterous.com/ there aren't any theme repositories (yet) since Posterous only recently got this feature. You can try to use existing tumblr themes, most of them should work, else you will have to [do slight modifications](http://posterous.com/theming/porting).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this post made by Speckyboy, [The Best Free to use Posterous Themes](http://speckyboy.com/2010/08/26/the-best-free-to-use-posterous-themes/).